# Storing and using leftover DME

Tags: storage, dme

I ended up with about a pound of CBW Sparkling Amber DME leftover.  I figured it might be worth keeping around so I put it in a plastic bag and tried to get as much air out as a could.  Since then I've left it in a box in at roughly room temperature (probably a little lower).

I'm considering adding some or all of it to an upcoming batch but hesitated when I saw that the Briess [product information sheet](http://www.brewingwithbriess.com/Assets/PDFs/Briess_PISB_CBWSparklingAmberDME.pdf) mentioned that "Storing opened bags is not recommended."  I'm hoping this may not apply to transferring it to a sealable bag since it seems that moisture and oxidation are the biggest factors for DME going bad, but for all I know I've potentially already over-exposed it.

It will have been stored about a month and would contribute about 5-10% of the sugars depending on the amount I use.  Would this re-packaged DME be worth using in a separate batch?  I'm thinking worst case scenario I could save it to use for a starter or something in the future.

Also, if it is not worth using, is there some other way I could have stored it to help it keep or is saving leftover malt basically just a lost cause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I bulk prime with DME, so it takes me 3 to 6 months to use a 1kg bag. I reseal the bag quickly, and place it in an airtight plastic container after pouring out the amount I require. No observable deterioration takes place.

Comment: I will say that after several months I've had DME turn into malt extract bricks due to humidity.

Answer (score 7):

If stored properly (no humidity and at room temperature or lower) the DME should preserve itself at least for a year.  It has been discussed before:  [How long will an extract kit stay good?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/4384/how-long-will-an-extract-kit-stay-good?rq=1)

In your case, if the seal was good, after a month it should still be fresh and you can use it without concerns...

Manufacturers will mention that "Storing opened bags is not recommended" but it is a way to protect themselves against complaints from people who do not use a good resealable bag.

Answer (score 3):

DME loves to suck up humidity and turn to a brick of sugar if it can.

What I do is cut the corner off the DME bag. Using a large mouth plastic bottle (gatorade) cut the top off 1 inch from the cap. Remove the lid and stuff the cut corner of the DME bag up through and fold back. Replace the cap for a nice airtight seal.

Then I store the DME with my specialty grains in an air tight drum.
[image]

Comment: Nice trick, but will the cap eventually cut the plastic?

Comment: Not that I've experienced, the bags are really thick.